# I have little lag on Offline Games

Tags: ps3, nba2k14

When I play MyPlayer mode on NBA 2k14 on my PS3 I usually have a little lag when I'm playing. It's really annoying to try a long shot and when I'm pressing button or using thumbstick the game stops for a moment and then continues. I can't play normally. Is a game problem? or my PS3 is going wrong? Does anyone have this problem.

I tried to turn off the quality of shot popup or also to turn off automatic strategy and It seems to improve the performance.

Comment: is this issue only happening on that game? Usually "offline lag" has to do with your TV. Check if "game mode" is activated.

Comment: I think your confusing lag with frame-rate. Try reducing the resolution and lowering some graphical settings (Anti-aliasing etc.)

Comment: This only happened when I played NBA2k12 and NBA2k14 other games like GTAV or SKYRIM works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you get this on any other game? Do you delete your mail from your inbox and have the same on lots of accounts?
turn off PS3 so the red light is on.
Hold and keep holding the power button. The console will turn on, and eventually turn off again.
Once off, with the red light on again, press and hold the power button. You will hear one beep, another single beep after that, and then two beeps in a row. After the two beeps, let go of the power button so it doesn't turn off again and you'll end up in the system recovery menu. From here there are a few options. Now this is important, DO NOT CLICK ON 'RESTORE PS3'. That will wipe the HDD clean. You don't want that...
What you want is the other two options, 'restore ps3 database' and 'restore ps3 file system'.
These two options will not delete any content on your HDD, but it will nuke any music playlists you have, and if you edited track information on any mp3s, say you renamed them all to something less ambigous than "track 01", the names and other altered data will revert.

Comment: That's sounds dangerous :S will it work?

Comment: Hi, sorry just seen the message, nope this is not dangerous, it's the PS3 version to defraging a computer :P

Comment: I think it works better. It still have a little lag sometimes but not as much like before.

Comment: Check the Options in the game as well, I know games like Black ops and Nier has a "install" feature, helps with lag as well as this will help increase the speed of the loading times :) You could always go buy a SSD and use that, will be the only thing to really cure the lag :)